# Ruby SSL_read: tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, client

I'm writing a simple ssl web client which worked fine without adding ssl support. Now that I have added ssl functionality to get request I get this error message:

> SSL_read: tlsv1 alert protocol version

After googling about it, I came to conclusion to check openssl version, which I can see that it supports TLSv1.2. I even created a context to explicitly forcing tlsv1.2 but still same error message. My openssl version:

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION' ===> OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

My code:

```
    require 'socket'
    require 'openssl'

    puts "Please select:"
    puts "get ==> to use GET method"
    puts "post ==> to use POST method"
    method = gets.chomp.downcase

    case method
    when "get"
      print "Please enter the domain name to get the http: "
      domain = "www." << gets.chomp
      print "Now enter the page you want to get: "
      page = gets.chomp

      # opening socket
      soc = TCPSocket.new domain, 443
      ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
      ctx.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2
      ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(soc, ctx)
      ssl.sync_close = true
      ssl.connect
      soc.puts "GET #{page} HTTP/1.1\nHost: #{domain}\n\n\n"
      while line = ssl.gets
        puts line
      end
    when "post"
      print "Please enter the domain name to post the http:"
      domain = gets.chomp.downcase
      print "Now enter the post form page:"
      form_page = gets.chomp.downcase
      puts "Please enter the parameters of POST and related values one at a time:"
      puts "(\"done\" to end input)"
      post_variable = []
      while true
        print "Parameter:"
        parameter = gets.chomp.downcase
        break if parameter == "done"
        print "Value:"
        value = gets.chomp.downcase
        break if  value == "done"
        post_variable.push("#{parameter}=#{value}")
        post_sentense = post_variable.join("&")
      end
      # opening socket
      soc = TCPSocket.new domain, 80
      soc.puts "POST #{form_page} HTTP/1.1\nHost: #{domain}\nContent-Length: #{post_sentense.length}\n\n\n#{post_variable}"
      while line = soc.gets
        puts line
      end
    else
      puts "wrong input!!!"
    end
```

I should mention that the domain name should be entered without www and page normally is `/index.html`.
Can someone help me through this???

Comment: This is an alert send by the server because it cannot handle the client. Without having more information about the server (i.e. URL if reachable from outside) it is impossible to say what's going on.

Comment: @grimfrog actually I tested this code google.com yahoo.com https://msn.com and I received same message from all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. This line:

```
soc.puts "GET #{page} HTTP/1.1\nHost: #{domain}\n\n\n"
```

should be this:

```
ssl.puts "GET #{page} HTTP/1.1\nHost: #{domain}\n\n\n"
```

I don't exactly know why but I think by sending the message to socket instead of ssl, it participated in ssl negotiation and didn't let negotiation to complete the process.